# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq

```
parcelas = (from docuRec in Dados.DOCUREC
                        where docuRec.CODALUNO == codAluno && docuRec.CODESCOLA == codEscola &&
                            (configBoleto.DtVencimentoInicial >= (docuRec.VENCESP != null ?
                            new DateTime(docuRec.DTVENCIMENTO.Year, docuRec.DTVENCIMENTO.Month, docuRec.VENCESP.Value) :
                                docuRec.DTVENCIMENTO))
                        select docuRec);
```

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Yes, you must use parameterless constructors in L2E. Hence you cannot use `new DateTime(y, m. d)`.

Comment: Either your entity does not have a parameterless constructor, or it is the construction of a DateTime within the query that is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In L2E you must have all your entities defining at least one parameterless constructor. That's necessary because the serializer must create an instance of your object and it doesn't know what parameters to pass;

The serializer then sets each property individually.

My guess is that `Dados.DOCUREC` doesn't define such a constructor.