# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Following is my linq query.

```
var values = (from test in entities.Table1
                                     select new Entity
                                     {
                                         Id = test.id,
                                         Value = test.name

                                     });
                    return values.ToList();
```

When Iam trying to run this, I am getting the following error :
`Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities`.

Comment: Is the `Entity` mapped to a table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217956/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti)

Answer (score 3):

Does your class entity have a parameterless constructor?  If not then you can't create a new instance for each record in your linq query because it doesn't know what to pass into the constructor to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing a bit more about your "context" would help, such as which version of .Net you're using, which version of EF, etc.

If I must guess only by the code and the error, it seems like that your `Entity` class doesn't have a parameterless (default) constructor. Try to check that.